# rename first two periods to hyphens

Tags: rename, file-management

I have the following command to change periods to hyphens in file names recursively, so long as they have another period both before and after them:

```
find path/to/dir -depth -type f -name '*.*' -exec rename -n -d 's/(?<=.)\.(?=.*\.)/-/g' {} +
```

However it cant be used effectively on all filenames I wish to adjust, and needs to be rewritten according to the following rules:

1. Renaming only occurs on filenames that start with a number.
2. Hidden files do not get changed.
3. Only the first two periods in every filename get changed.

Eg: `2020.12.06_name123.ext.xmp` becomes `2020-12-06_name123.ext.xmp` while `name123.ext.xmp` remains unchanged.

How to solve?

Running linux mint cinnamon 21

Comment: Your command doesn't check that there is a period before the period being changed to a hyphen. It would rename `a.b.xmp` to `a-b.xmp` for example. Is that what you want? You are not escaping the `.` in the lookbehind.

Comment: Are the positions of dots constant?

Comment: @RomeoNinov For the files I want to change, yes - it is always the yyyy.mm.dd format at the beginning of the filename. However, there are files I do not wish to change - these do not start with numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could just use `zsh` and do:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(<1900-2100>).(<1-12>).(<1-31>)([^0-9]*)(#q.)' '$1$2-$3-$4$5'
```

To be explicit as to what you want to match (here file names starting with a YYYY.MM.DD¹ date in a given range).

(`-n` for dry-run. Remove it to actually do it).

---

<sup>¹ technically, that would also match on `002023.1.012`, the `<x-y>` matches on any sequence of decimal digits that represent a number between *x* and *y*.</sup>

Comment: If I run just the first line I get:
`autoload: command not found`

If I run it all I also get:
`Command 'zmv' not found`

Comment: @ItHertz it sounds like you're not using the `zsh` shell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example with `awk` which assume name start with number, the positions of dots is fixed and the delimiter between date and the rest is underscore:

```
awk -F_ 'BEGIN {OFS="_"} /^[0-9]/ {a=gensub(".","-",5,$1);b=gensub(".","-",8,a);$1=b }1'
```

And here is the entire `find`:

```
find  -depth -type f -name '*.*" -exec  awk -F_ 'BEGIN {OFS="_"} /^[0-9]/ {a=gensub(".","-",5,$1);b=gensub(".","-",8,a);$1=b }1' {} +
```